# How did Artemis Fowl contact Mulch Diggums in The Time Paradox?

Tags: artemis-fowl, artemis-fowl-the-time-paradox

I was re-reading *Artemis Fowl: The Time Paradox* and couldn't help but miss how Artemis contacted Mulch when he and Holly are stuck in the trunk of the car.

Artemis did not plan to be in the car (as he did not plan for past-Butler to put them there), yet Mulch seems to appear magically having received a message from Artemis.  Did Artemis send a message to Mulch and if so, how?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Mulch mentions a note being sent back in time when he realises the two are time travelers.

> The dwarf was actually doing a little jig now. "No. No, it all adds up. You're talking about *future* events in the *past* tense. You sent back a note so that I would come and rescue you here and now"
>
> <sub>*Artemis Fowl: The Time Paradox*, Ch 6, p 109</sub>

When they come back to their main timeline, they ask Number One if they could send a note back in time so that Mulch could save them.

> "I need you to send a note back in time"
>
> "I've been ordered not to open the time stream again, but maybe we can squeeze back one more thing," said Number One.
>
> Artemis nodded. "That's what I thought."
>
> "When and where?"
>
> "Holly knows, you can do it from Tara."
>
> "How do you spell *stupendous*?" said Holly, smiling.
>
> <sub>*Artemis Fowl: The Time Paradox*, Ch 16, p 359</sub>

Comment: Thank you very much - This is exactly what I wanted.